# Drop down list styling, can't get the padding right

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

What seemed like an easy task has become hours of puzzling by now.
I have a `dropdownlist (@html.dropdownlistfor(model))`, which I style via `css ( new { @class = "searchDropDownList" } )`

The thing is, the standard dropdown list is too short (height-wise), but when I add height to make the box bigger, the selected item is not centered anymore. `vertical-align: middle` doesnt work on the selected item.

When I add padding to the top of the box, the text goes down as I want, but when you would then hover the textbox, you can see the Selection Arrow being croocked, since that ones also goes down.

See pictures:

- **Firefox**:

[image]

- **Chrome**:

[image]

Does anyone know how to lower only the text?

EDIT:
Current css:

```
.searchDropDownList {
  display: inline;   
  width: 114px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px auto auto 2px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;      
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-top: auto;
  line-height: 10px; 
}
```

Changing the `padding-top: auto;` to `3px` results in the images posted above.

Comment: If you order your css alphabetically, **sometimes** it's easier to read. Could you add your html as well?